# How do I convert the tables in a SQL dump into a graph in neo4j along with the data in the tables?

Tags: sql, neo4j, relational-database, graph-databases

I have a SQL dump containing nearly 8000 tables. I have to convert this to a graph in neo4j. The graph should contain all the foreign key relationships between the tables. How do I approach this problem?

I tried creating all the nodes of a prototype database of tables containing only a few tables. However I was not able to depict the foreign key relationship between the tables. I have to create the graph such that deleting a particular entity (record or single row in a relational database like SQL) will delete all the nodes related to it also.

Comment: Some documentation that may help: https://neo4j.com/labs/etl-tool/ and https://neo4j.com/labs/neo4j-migrations/

Comment: Not sure for Neo4j, but you could do it for AWS Neptune. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Neptune.html

Comment: Memgraph, that also uses Cypher has, few tutorials that might be interesting to you: https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/tutorials/migrate-relational-database, https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data/migrate/mysql, https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data/migrate/postgresql

Comment: There is also Liquibase for Neo4j: https://neo4j.com/labs/liquibase/docs/. If you managed your RDBMS migrations with Liquibase, Liquibase for Neo4j could translate some of the relational constructs into the graph.

Comment: @KWriter - please stop spamming all Neo4j/Cypher questions with unneeded tags such as [tag:memgraphdb] - this, as well as [tag:opencypher], don't apply to any Neo4j+Cypher questions (aside from specific OpenCypher questions, or questions directly related to memgraph. These tags can also be seen as spam, as they serve to promote an alternative product.